# Url rewriting in Apache HTTPD with mod_cluster

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, jboss, mod-cluster

I am new to Apache. I have 2 jboss (Jboss as 7.1.1) and apache httpd server. I am using mod_cluster for load balancing. I wish to hide the jboss url from user and wish to show the user clean urls.

for e.g.

www.mydomain.com will be having my static website.
subdomain.mydomain.com should go to mydomain.com:8080/myapp
subdomain.mydomain.com/mypage.xhtml should go to mydomain.com:8080/myapp/mypage.xhtml
sumdomain.mydomain.com/myservice should go to mydomain.com:8080/myapp/service.xhtml?name=myservice

I have tried many things with no success. Can some one tell me if it is possible or not. And if possible what are the things I should do.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you cannot do what you want is because you are trying to solve two very different problem at once. Separate them and solve them individually.

**Load balancer:** I usually use Proxy for load balancer. For example

```
<Proxy balancer://mycluster>
BalancerMember http://wn1.seco.com
BalancerMember http://wn2.seco.com
</Proxy>
ProxyPass /test balancer://mycluster
```

**Redirect and Forwarding:** use mode_rewrite to redirect specific URLs to a different ones.

```
RewriteEngine  on
RewriteRule    "^/foo\.html$"  "/bar.html" [PT]
```

Comment: Thanks @user2984552 for the prompt reply. Can I achieve what I want to achieve with Proxy instead of mod cluster.

Comment: Yes you can. Read more about what using apache for load balancer and how to use apache to redirect specific url pathern. And there is a difference between Redirect and Forwarding. Make sure you know which one you need.

Answer (score 0):

You can use mod_cluster and still stay in control of ProxyPass directives. E.g. `CreateBalancers 1` and then you could create the Proxies yourself `ProxyPassMatch ^/static/ !
ProxyPass / balancer://qacluster stickysession=JSESSIONID|jsessionid nofailover=on
ProxyPassReverse / balancer://qacluster
ProxyPreserveHost on`. See [the relevant docs for mod_cluster 1.3.1.Final](http://docs.jboss.org/mod_cluster/1.3.0/html_single/#d0e548).